# Error in angular unit test cases: TypeError: this.userService.currentUser.subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am getting this error while running angular unit test cases:

**Test Result**

```
SidebarComponent
   × should create
    TypeError: this.userService.currentUser.subscribe is not a function
```

**sidebar.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('SidebarComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SidebarComponent>;
  let mockUserService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockUserService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['currentUser']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [SidebarComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [{ provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService }]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SidebarComponent);
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    mockUserService.currentUser.and.returnValue(of('Here goes an object'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(SidebarComponent).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**sidebar.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(currentUser => {
        // Some code here
    });
}
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "9.6.23",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "protractor": "6.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "0.1.7",
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class UserService {
  private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject({});
  public currentUser: Observable<User> = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

  setUser(user) {
      this.currentUserSubject.next({ ...newUser });
  }
}
```

As far I know to solve this question we need to use of in following statement:

> mockUserService.currentUser.and.returnValue(of('Here goes an object'));

where of is imported from 'rxjs'. When I log the value of of('Here goes an object') it shows that it's observable.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: can you post `userService` code here

Comment: Added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some work on this test, I found that we cannot use spyOn(userService, 'currentUser'). The reason is clear that the currentUser is not a function, but a variable in which we have assigned an observable. SpyOn will create a fake function on this, but what we need is an observable. So we can use userService.setUser method to set the value of currentUser appropirately.

**sidebar.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('SidebarComponent', () => {
  let component: SidebarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SidebarComponent>;
  let userService: UserService;

  beforeEach(done => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
    declarations: [SidebarComponent],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
  })
  .compileComponents()
  .then(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SidebarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
    userService.setUser(userInfo);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    done();
  });
 });

 it('should create', done => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   done();
 });
})
```

Answer (score 4):

What about using `spyOn` to mock specific method of service:

```
const userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
const mockedResponse = {}; // Modify as per your need
spyOn(userService, 'currentUser').and.callFake(() => {
  return of(mockedResponse);
});
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your mocking something like that:

```
export const mockUserService= {
    currentUser = {
        subscribe() {
          return of({ 
              // whatever here
          });
        }
    }
};
```

The code creates a fake service. This fake service you can add all the functions and members that are used by your component that is tested.

Comment: Why can't we use the following way ?
    mockUserService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['currentUser']); 
I know I can write the complete mock service but it will un-necessary increase the code for me, because there will be so many services to mock.

Comment: Not sure... maybe that could also work: jasmine.createSpyObj([{currentUser = {subscribe() {...}}]);